# Printed report from an SQL result

Tags: sql

I've written some SQL code to run on my iSeries system.  It compares the contents of two files to make sure previous copies copied all objects into a new library.  My results display fine, but I want to create a hard copy rather than having it display on my console.  What do I need to add to my code?

```
select cppgenlf.odobnm, cppgenlf2.odobnm   
  from cppgenlf                             
  full outer join cppgenlf2 on cppgenlf.odobnm = cppgenlf2.odobnm       
  order by cppgenlf.odobnm
```

Comment: This is not in the scope of SQL. You need an application for this.

Comment: By "hard copy" do you mean to store the results of the select in another "third" table? If so use `create table third as select ...`.

Comment: @TheImpaler, By hard copy he mean On Printer.

Comment: Then I agree with Aknit Bajpai. That's not SQL but application related.

Comment: @Steve Hard copy certainly means printed. Do you mean printed onto paper or are you looking for a file to be created (soft copy)?

Comment: I wanted to print it onto paper, but if I can create a file that would be ok as well.  I can write an AS400 query over the file and then generate a listing from that.  Thank you.